# SQL Join With Fallback

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
    Id INT NOT NULL
    Zip NVARCHAR(5) NULL    
    ZipPlus4 NVARCHAR(9) NULL

CREATE TABLE ZipLookup
    Zip NVARCHAR(5) NULL    
    Code NVARCHAR(10) NULL

CREATE TABLE ZipPlus4Lookup
    ZipPlus4 NVARCHAR(9) NULL    
    Code NVARCHAR(10) NULL
```

And data like

```
Addresses
1 | 92123 | 921234444

ZipLookup
92123 | Type A

ZipPlus4Lookup
921234444 | Type B
```

Is it possible to construct a query such that:

- A given row in Addresses is outer joined to ZipPlus4Lookup if there is a match

  Addresses.ZipPlus4 = ZipPlus4Lookup.ZipPlus4
- Otherwise, the given row in Addresses is outer joined to ZipLookup if there is a match

  Addresses.Zip = ZipLookup.Zip
- Otherwise neither table is outer joined

*In plain English, the Addresses table has a Zip and a ZipPlus4 column and I need to look up a code using the most precise match.  If there's a match on Zip+4, use the code from that match.  Otherwise, use the code from a Zip match.*

I wish I had an attempted query to share, but with this one I don't know where to start.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This basic query will work:

```
SELECT
   A.*,
   Code = IsNull(Z4.Code, Z.Code)
FROM
   dbo.Addresses A
   LEFT JOIN dbo.ZipPlus4Lookup Z4
      ON A.ZipPlus4 = Z4.ZipPlus4
   LEFT JOIN dbo.ZipLookup Z
      ON A.Zip = Z.Zip
      AND Z4.ZipPlus4 IS NULL;
```

Or you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
   A.*,
   Z.Code
FROM
   dbo.Addresses A
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 Code
      FROM (
         SELECT 0, Code FROM dbo.ZipPlus4Lookup Z4
         WHERE A.ZipPlus4 = Z4.ZipPlus4
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, Code FROM dbo.ZipLookup Z
         WHERE A.Zip = Z.Zip
      ) X (Seq, Code)
      ORDER BY X.Seq
   ) Z;
```

They may have different performance characteristics. It's worth testing. My guess is the second query is unnecessary but it's still conceptually possible to be better.

See these in action [in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd3a3/1).

Comment: I don't understand `AND Z4.ZipPlus4 IS NULL`.  The actual ZipPlus4Lookup table will not have any NULL entries, but rather there just may not be any match.  What is that line accomplishing?

Comment: Since the join to `Zip4PlusLookup` is a `LEFT JOIN`, in the final rowset *every column* in `ZipPlus4Lookup` for an `Address` with a failed `ZipPlus4` match will be NULL. Since the `IS NULL` condition is *outside of* and *after* the join to `ZipPlus4Lookup`, it will give the query optimizer a chance to optimize away the final condition if the Z4 lookup has already succeeded. Note that putting the `Z4.ZipPlus4 IS NULL` condition inside its own `LEFT JOIN` would do exactly as you are suggesting--prevent any match from working at all.

Comment: @EricJ.:  The `AND Z4.ZipPlus4 IS NULL` means only join `ZipLookup` if there is no match in `ZipPlus4Lookup`.  It's not really necessary, because `IsNull(Z4.Code, Z.Code)` will ignore `ZipLookup` if a `ZipPlus4Lookup` match is found anyway, but maybe it has a positive performance impact (I'm not sure).

Comment: @gmm I'm not sure either but I'm sure it won't have a significant negative impact, so I threw it in. I think it also makes it explicitly clear to any future viewers of the query what is intended.

Comment: @ErikE:  Yep, that makes sense.  By the way, here is an [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed3eb/1) that shows the solution in action.  Both queries work.

Comment: @gmm Thank you, I added it to my answer with one row of the other type as well.

Comment: @ErikE:  Good idea, adding an example of the other type.

Comment: Is there anyway to only do the fallback join if it doesn't match?

Comment: @sarora The first version above basically already does that. The JOIN condition for the second join includes a `WHERE IS NULL` that lets the query optimizer know that the second join depends on the first. Even though the execution plan shows the second join present (since it has to know how to join to that table, thus it must be present), in practice, you should see 0 reads on that join when the first join does return a row. Are you seeing something different from this?

Comment: I’m using the second query with the outer apply…and that appears not be optimized. I guess I could try the first query now that I understand it, but frankly it feels like a bit cryptic, which isn’t ideal for collaborative work / maintenance.

Comment: @sarora The first query is more cryptic than the second query? Do what works, what is required for your SLA. Add comments to explain it, if you think that will help.

Comment: Sure.. I get that. I guess I’m still digging for another way to express fallback logic, while having some short-circuiting. The 2nd query is more expressive but does every left join (5 times in my code) which affects performance. I appreciate the first answer as being the only viable option I’ve found so far.

Comment: @sarora Can you add the `WHERE SOMETHING IS NULL` expression to those OUTER APPLY clauses to get similar functionality?